# How to configure ubuntu server with 2 NICs, and 2 Gateways (2nd as a failover)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, routing, failover

Here is a basic overview of the network configuration for one of our servers:

```
[Datacenter]
    [Internet Connection #1] >> [Firewall 1 (xx.xx.xx.1)] >> [Server (xx.xx.xx.10)]  
                             >> [Firewall 2 (xx.xx.xx.2)] >> [Server (xx.xx.xx.10)]  

    [Internet Connection #2] >> [Firewall 1 (xx.xx.xx.1)] >> [Server (xx.xx.xx.10)]  
                             >> [Firewall 2 (xx.xx.xx.2)] >> [Server (xx.xx.xx.10)]
```

The server is a hypervisor and the ubuntu machine i'm having trouble with is a VM.
The VM has 2 network interfaces (one on each network) and the IP addresses etc is all configured by DHCP running on the firewalls.

So here's where we're at:

```
eth0
    Gets a DHCP lease and is assigned IP address: xx.xx.xx.143
eth1
    Gets a DHCP lease and is assigned IP address: xx.xx.xx.243
```

However i am unsure where to go from here.

The problem is when I:

```
ping google.com
```

It hangs and times out, this can be resolved by disconnecting a NIC.
I am pretty sure this is an issue with routing.

I have seen a few tutorials on advanced routing and "the waters a bit deep for me!"
Can anyone provide me descriptive steps on how to configure this?

I should also note that the ubuntu server should use xx.xx.xx.1 as the default gate way and by default all traffic should happen on eth0, but if the firewall goes down should use xx.xx.xx.2 and eth1 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can gather you're looking for a solution to your problem more than a learning experience, I'd personally suggest you take a look at NIC bonding..

[NIC bonding on Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding)

Does exactly what it says on the tin. Provides redundancy and an increase in performance.

[Link Aggregation and High Availability with Bonding](http://linux-ip.net/html/ether-bonding.html)

Comment: Thanks, does bonding work with multiple gateways?

Comment: Bonding will make the two NIC's act as one, what are your reasons for multiple gateways? Redundancy? The advanced routing is going to be a nightmare either way but if it's not for redundancy..

Comment: If you choose multiple NIC's you can use the route command and manually add in routes to specific networks from each interface. You will also nee the IP for the router that knows of the other network. For intstance if I know that 192.168.100.1 knows about the 10.10.10.0 network, I could use the command 
route add -net 10.10.10.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.100.1
Of course for this to work, the other side will need to know how to route packets back to you.

The default gateway though is where your computer will send any packet that it does not have route information for.

Answer (score 2):

If advanced routing is a bit difficult for you then I would not recommend this approach.

The problem is that by default each dhcp lease will claim the default route and also update the list of dns servers. Then there is the firewall issue: how to detect when the it is down, etc

Buying a cheap and easy to configure router might just be better for you.

Comment: I should clarify: I'm a learn by doing kinda guy.. And i'm not against advanced routing at all i'd just like somebody to explain this kind of configuration.. that way I learn and then the next person like me has a place to go to learn too!

Comment: Sorry, perhaps the downvote was a bit harsh on my part!

Comment: I suggest not using DHCP inside the DMZ.  The convenience/security tradeoff between the firewalls is different than for the interior network.  Diagram the network for yourself, including addresses.

Answer (score 0):

DHCP in this scenario will periodically break your routing that you've set up. You are actually trying to solve two challenges as well: You'd like Active/Passive NICs and you'd like a failover gateway.

1. Have a look at [the Ubuntu wiki on NIC bonding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBonding) and specifically you want to set `mode=1` in your options for active/passive.
2. You can achieve a failover gateway by setting the metric of that gateway to higher than o. The metric value is used ot determine route "cost", and it will always use the lowest cost available first.

If you're feeling pro, it seems you can adjust the time it takes to fail over as well. Have a look at http://mailman.ds9a.nl/pipermail/lartc/2002q1/002667.html for a talked through example. I've never tried this myself though.